# How do I remove all folders in a tree of folders that contain no files or folders that contain other files with powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I need a powershell script that will remove all folders in a tree that do not contain files **or other folders underneath it that contain files.**

I'd love to also be able to optionally qualify this with a file age check to cleanup files as well older than x days and then perform the folder cleanup as well.

The tree could be very complex with many folders within folders and files buried deep within those folders.

It cannot remove a folder that has folders in it that contain files.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do you just fine.

```
# Get all directories beneath $root (whatever your $root may be)
Get-ChildItem -Path $root -Directory -Recurse |
   Where-Object {
      # Determine if each directory had children
      -not (Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Recurse)      
   } |
   # Remove the -WhatIf if you want to actually remove
   Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

Two additional notes:

1. The example above includes -WhatIf, so that it doesn't actually delete your files.  Simply remove -WhatIf to delete them.
2. The script does not look for hidden files or folders.  To make it do that, add a -Force to each Get-ChildItem